# How to break on custom exceptions in VS2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have several custom exceptions that are thrown throughout my application. Besides just setting a breakpoint in the constructor, is there anyway I can break on these exceptions in the same way I do with native exceptions from Exception Settings?

Comment: Are you sure you aren't using exceptions as results? Why would you want to stop only on *some* exceptions? Exceptions are the equivalent of a blown fuse

Comment: 401 project solution at work. No control over peoples' unfortunate use of exceptions lol. I'm actually just trying to see why some exceptions are getting thrown hundreds of times and making the debugger have a panic attack

Comment: Being in a similar position, I fail to see anything funny with this. Or the web server meltdowns that can happen *in production* when the exceptions push the CPU so high that the server can't serve new requests. I'll also bet there are a lot of `catch {}` statements to hide the exceptions

Comment: I actually have a shelveset with the worst culprits of exception throwing locally commented out. It's the worst in our cache service, which makes initialization unbearably slow.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can add Exceptions in to the Exception Settings Window. Add it there (probably to Common Language Runtime Exceptions), then mark to break on it

Comment: Great, this works. It also looks like checking "<All Common Language Runtime Exceptions not in this list>" will break on all derived exceptions, assuming you dont add any manually

Comment: Don't forget the namespace to the custom exception